# Calculating 'color distance' between 2 points in a 3-dimensional space

Tags: java

I have a homework task where I have to write a class responsible for contour detection. It is essentially an image processing operation, using the definition of euclidean distance between 2 points in the 3-dimensional space. Formula given to us to use is:

Math.sqrt(Math.pow(pix1.red - pix2.red,2) + Math.pow(pix1.green- pix2.green,2) + Math.pow(pix1.blue- pix2.blue,2));

We need to consider each entry of the two dimensional array storing the colors of the pixels of an image, and if some pixel, pix, the color distance between p and any of its neighbors is more than 70, change the color of the pixel to black, else change it to white.

We are given a seperate class as well responsible for choosing an image, and selecting an output, for which method operationContouring is applied to.  Java syntax and convention is very new to me having started with python. Conceptually, I'm struggling to understand what the difference between pix1 and pix2 is, and how to define them. This is my code so far.

Given:

```
import java.awt.Color;

/* Interface for ensuring all image operations invoked in same manner */
public interface operationImage {
    public Color[][] operationDo(Color[][] imageArray);
}
```

My code:

```
    import java.awt.Color;

public class operationContouring implements operationImage {

    public Color[][] operationDo(Color[][] imageArray) {
        int numberOfRows = imageArray.length;
        int numberOfColumns = imageArray[0].length;

        Color[][] results = new Color[numberOfRows][numberOfColumns];

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < numberOfColumns; j++) {
                int red =  imageArray[i][j].getRed();
                int green = imageArray[i][j].getGreen();
                int blue = imageArray[i][j].getBlue();              

                double DistanceColor =  Math.sqrt(Math.pow(pix1.red - pix2.red,2) + Math.pow(pix1.green- pix2.green,2) + Math.pow(pix1.blue- pix2.blue,2));

                int LIMIT = 70;

                if (DistanceColor> LIMIT ) {
                    results[i][j] = new Color((red=0), (green=0), (blue=0));
                }
                else {
                    results[i][j] = new Color((red=255), (green=255), (blue=255));
                }
            }
        return results;
    }

}
```

Comment: pix1 and pix2 are adjacent pixels, the colors thereof represented with Color objects. Define pix1 as imageArray[i][j] and then test the pixels surrounded it as pix2.

Comment: `pix1` is the pixel you are checking (e.g. `imageArray[i][j]`), `pix2` is one of its neighbors (e.g. `imageArray[i+1][j]`, `imageArray[i][j+1]`, ...), that is, you must do a second pair of loops (e.g. `imageArray[i+1][j]`, `imageArray[i][j+1]`, ...) and you can use `Color.WHITE` and `Color.BLACK` for the result

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution I wrote that uses BufferedImages. I tested it and it should work. Try changing it such that it uses your data format (Color[][]) and it should work for you too. Note that "pix1" is nothing more than a description of the color of some pixel, and "pix2" is the description of the color of the pixel you are comparing it to (determining whether the color distance > 70).

```
public static boolean tooDifferent(Color c1, Color c2) {
    return  Math.sqrt(Math.pow(c1.getRed() - c2.getRed(),2) + Math.pow(c1.getGreen()- c2.getGreen(),2) + Math.pow(c1.getBlue()- c2.getBlue(),2)) > 70;
}

public static Color getColor(int x, int y, BufferedImage img) {
    return new Color(img.getRGB(x, y));
}


public static BufferedImage operationDo(BufferedImage img) {
    int numberOfRows = img.getHeight();
    int numberOfColumns = img.getWidth();

    BufferedImage results = new BufferedImage(numberOfColumns, numberOfRows, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    for (int y = 0; y < numberOfRows; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < numberOfColumns; x++) {
            Color color = new Color(img.getRGB(x, y));

            boolean aboveExists = y > 0;
            boolean belowExists = y < numberOfRows - 1;
            boolean leftExists = x > 0;
            boolean rightExists = x < numberOfColumns - 1;

            if ((aboveExists && tooDifferent(color, getColor(x, y - 1, img))) ||
                    (belowExists && tooDifferent(color, getColor(x, y + 1, img))) ||
                    (leftExists && tooDifferent(color, getColor(x - 1, y, img))) ||
                    (rightExists && tooDifferent(color, getColor(x + 1, y, img)))) {
                results.setRGB(x, y, Color.black.getRGB());
            } else {
                results.setRGB(x, y, Color.white.getRGB());
            }

        }
    }
    return results;
}
```